# jquery load with asp.net MVC partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, partial

I have a partial view and I want to render it in main view using jquery.

Here is how I am coding the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dvGames").load("/LiveGame/Partial3");
});
```

where as controller method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Partial3(DateTime gameDate)
{
    return View("Partial3");
}
```

I dont see anything. I tried

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("Partial3"); %>
```

and it works but I want to filter data in partial view so I am using jquery load method.

Comment: Is the call making into your action method? Do you hit a breakpoint if one is set?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your controller action requires a DateTime parameter that you need to supply when invoking the AJAX request:

```
$(function() {
    $('#dvGames').load(
        '<%= Url.Action("Partial3", "LiveGame") %>', 
        { gameDate: '2011-03-06' }
    );
});
```

Comment: +1 - also, i think the ActionResult Partial3 should be returning a partialview(), rather than a view()!?

Answer (score 0):

Try letting the framework create the URL. Use the

```
<%= Url.Action("LiveGame","Partial3") %>
```

Comment: It is not going in controller action. and I used   <%= Url.Action("LiveGame","Partial3") %>     and it is printing:  "/Partial3/LiveGame " on the screen. I need to load partial view.

Comment: Instead of hard coding the URL in the load, try using the URL.Action method. Also are you supplying the gameDate parameter?

Comment: @ rcravens I am used url.action as I mentioned above but it printed the value instead of going to that partial view. I need to supply gameDate parameter. How can I do this ?

Comment: Add it as a query parameter. url?gameDate='date'

Comment: @rcavens and how to use url.action